# If $f$satisfies $|f(z)|=1 \ \forall z\in A=\{z: |z| = 1 \}$ then it vanishes in $\mathbb D (0,1)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

> If $f$ is an entire non-constant function satisfying $|f(z)|=1 \  \forall z\in A=\{z: |z| = 1 \}$ then there exists $z\in \mathbb D (0,1)$ such that $f(z)=0$.

I'm trying to prove this following [this hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253138/let-f-be-a-non-constant-entire-function-such-that-left-lvert-fz-right-lv), but I don't really know how to use it.

Suppose $f$ doesn't vanishes in $\mathbb D (0,1)$. Then $1/f$ is 
 well defined and it is a composition of holomorphic functions and thus holomorphic in $\mathbb D$, satisfying $1/|f(z)|=1$ in $A$. How can we use the Maximum principle here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $\left\lvert\frac1f\right\rvert$ has a maximum on $\overline{\mathbb D}$ (since $\overline{\mathbb D}$ is compact). If that maximum is greater than $1$, it is loccated at $\mathbb D$ and therefore, by the maximum principle, $\frac1f$ is constant, which is impossible, since $\bigl\lvert f(z)\bigr\rvert=1$ when $\lvert z\rvert=1$. So, a contradiction is reached, and $\frac1f$ doesn't exist. So, $f$ has a zero.

And if the maximum is located at the boundary of $\mathbb D$, that $\lvert f\rvert=1$, and, again by the maximum principle, $f$ is constant.